# How to send and confirm that message delivered to RabbitMQ in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq

I have web service that handles requests and publishes messages to RabbitMQ (Written in spring boot). 
The problem is when there is no connection I cannot detect it immediately and I am losing all my messages.  How can I deal with this problem? I got AMQP Connection error after 30 seconds. In that interval I cannot handle this problem. I want to know when message delivered to RabbitMQ. If it is not delivered I need to store all messages and when rabbitmq is up resend all these messages.  By the way, performance is important.
I have read documentations below. I think it could be solved with OperationsCallback but I dont know how..

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#scoped-operations
- https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#cf-pub-conf-ret

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

its rather a rabbit MQ feature more than java or spring, which allows any message that is published to be acknowledged back to the publisher, see the below link for references on how:
https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html

Comment: I did what was written but did not help me. I am missing 3-4 messages while it checks connection is alive or not